# Java - Tapestry - html does not interpret <br> from database

Tags: java, html, sql, tapestry

I´m making a news system for my web application. 
When I insert a new news I replace all my new lines `\n` for `< br>` in java.
So my news description column on my database is something like this:

```
This is new 01.<br> In this new blablabla.<br>End of this new.
```

When I do `${new.description}` in my HTML file it does not interpret `<br>` so I get the same string in my html page (`< br>` included and not substituted).

What am I forgetting? It should work perfectly.

Comment: @kurt could you help me? I´m new on this.

Comment: When you look at the source code of your webpage, is the `<br>` written as `<br>` or `&lt;br&gt;`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly It´s displayed as <br>, same as my database.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Let me look again.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I was wrong. At the source code it displays &lt;br /&gt.

Comment: Have you tried just leaving the `/n` and seeing if they get parsed into `<br>`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Let me try. I´m goona put /n in my database.

Comment: @JonnyHenly It does not work. If it´s \n on my database, my web page shows \n too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the OutputRaw. I have < br> in my database column.
My code now is:

```
<t:outputraw value="${new.description}"/>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a FYI: Yes with this component you can render data without html entity encoding which is done by default for security reasons. So be aware with using this with data that has been entered by possible suspicious users.